# Every non-zero prime ideal of $K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension

Let $R=K[x,y]/(f)$ where $f(x,y)=y^2-x^3$. 
I can show that $R$ is an integral domain and Noetherian. I have to show that every non-zero prime ideal of $R$ is maximal, but I can not realize the form of ideals of $R$.

I try to choose a prime ideal $P$ and want to show $R/P$ is (finite integral domain so is field) or any element in $R/P$ has inverses.

Any other suggestion. and please write me form of element such a ring. and I dont know what is identity of $R/P$

thanks a lot

Comment: If there is a prime ideal of $R=K[x,y]/(y^2-x3)$ that is not maximal, it means $R$ has Krull dimension $\ge 2$, hence $K[x,y]$ has dimension $\ge 3$. Now  it is known that Krull dimension of a polynomial ring over a field has Krull dimension equal to the number of indeterminates.

Comment: I dont understand the part of dimension of $K [x,y] $ larger or equal than $3$ @Bernard

Comment: $R$ has a chain ot at least three prime ideals $(0)\subset\mathfrak p_1\mathfrak p_2$, corresponding to a chain $(y^2-x^3)\subset \mathfrak p_1'\subset \mathfrak p_2'$ in $K[x,y]$, whence the chain  $(0)\subset (y^2-x^3)\subset \mathfrak p_1'\subset \mathfrak p_2'$ in $K[x,y]$.

Comment: @Bernard I tried to prove by showlng $R $ is isomorphic to $K [t^2,t^3] $ but thanks a lot for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3)\simeq K[T^2,T^3]$, and the extension $K[T^2,T^3]\subset K[T]$ is integral, so $\dim K[T^2,T^3]=\dim K[T]=1$.